# Is the Singular Value Decomposition a measurable function?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrix-decomposition, svd, borel-sets

Consider the SVD of rectangular matrices as operators

$$ svd : \mathbb C^{n\times m} \to \mathbb U_n \times \mathbb D_{n,m}\times \mathbb U_m $$

where $\mathbb U$ is the space of $n\times n$ unitary matrices and $\mathbb D_{n,m}$ is the space of real nonnegative diagonal rectangular matrices.

We know that this operator is not well defined, since there's more than one SVD for each matrix.

What I want to know is, there exists a specification of $svd$ on $\mathbb C^{n\times m}$ that makes it a Borel-measurable function?

I already know that it can't be continuous, and that if I play enough with the signs of the entries, I guess I can make it not even Lebesgue measurable, but what I need here is for just one specification. If I had to try to do it, I guess I'd try to define it locally and then try to glue together the charts, but I feel like it might badly backfire.

Comment: Define the $svd$ map locally on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ of matrices with distinct singular values. I think this can be done as an analytic map. The rest of the domain of $svd$ is a Lebesgue null set.

Comment: @HansEngler The problem is that null set are not all Borel

Comment: The set of complex matrices $A$ where $A^\ast A$ has multiple eigenvalues is an analytic space afaik. Does that help?.

Comment: The SVD is not unique. It should not be difficult however, based on measurable selection theorems to prove that there is a measurable selection function.

Comment: @HansEngler yeah, technically it is a closed set, but even so it is not enough to conclude I think

Comment: [Possibly somewhat related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/369930/91764)